# why $e^{q.2 \pi i}=1^q ?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers

Prove that $\frac {\mathbb{Q}} {\mathbb{Z}}$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative  group  of root  of unity  in $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$

**My attempt**: I found the  answer  [here](https://linearalgebras.com/solution-abstract-algebra-exercise-3-1-14.html)

It is written  that

> Define  a  mapping   $f : \mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}  \to \mathbb{C}^{\times} $ by $q \to 1^q$ is a  isomorphism

**My thinking** :  The natural  choice for  the isomorphism  is  $q \to  e^{q.2 \pi i}$

But here $e^{q.2 \pi i}=\cos q.2 \pi  + i \sin q 2 \pi \neq 1^q$

**My question** : why  $e^{q.2 \pi i}=1^q ?$

Comment: You might start with $e^{2 \pi i}=1$

Comment: Writing $1^q$ is incredibly confusing and I have no idea why the source would do so.

Comment: In the complex numbers, "$q$-th root" is not single-valued. So you can't write $1^q$ without specifying how you are taking the $q$th root. For example, what is "$1^{1/4}$"? Is it $1$, $-1$, $i$, or $-i$? All four of them have the property that their fourth power is $1$.